# Send Parameter View Modal to App-Delegate File (Xamarain)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I am a Xamarin developer I implement **app switching** in my project and it's done for the android version but I don't have an idea how to do it for the IOs version

When I use the open URL function in my view controller it's working

```
~if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
   {
      try{
            var param = new NSDictionary();
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("URL that want to pass"), param, (completed) =>
                {});
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString(), "123456");
                   }
          }
    }~
```

but when the app-center built APK for the android it's failed and getting me an error cause of the UIKit library

So I want to pass the parameter(**Deeplink URL**) from my view modal to App-Delegate File but I am not to much aware about the xamarin so I am not able to do this

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: code needs to be posted and formatted as text, not images.  That is an SO site rule

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials: Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=ios).

You can use `Launcher` class directly in Forms project to open a URI, this is often used when deep linking into another application's **custom URI schemes**.

##### Sample

```
var supportsUri = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("lyft://");
if (supportsUri) 
   await Launcher.OpenAsync("lyft://ridetype?id=lyft_line");
```

In iOS 9 and greater, Apple enforces what schemes an application can query for. To specify which schemes you would like to use, you must specify **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in your **Info.plist** file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>lyft</string>  
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I want to implement deep linking for the Payment gateway Application (MobilePay) by using a launcher, Can manage the response after complete payment in the Payment Application (MobilePay), Which Means it's can come back in our main application and get call back data.

Comment: In this scenario you need to [integrate appswitch sdk in xamairn project](https://github.com/MobilePayDev/MobilePay-AppSwitch-SDK/wiki/Cross-platform) , the sdk should be able to allow you to come back to main project if payment complete .

Comment: I am completely deep linking for the android version without any SDK, And when I try  to install MobilePay SDK it's getting me error "This package may not be fully compatible with your project" something like

Comment: You need to warp the sdk into binding library and use it in xamairn .

Comment: I am not aware of this, So let me know if have any guidance on this.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference about for the same

Comment: First approach : find ios sdk for MobilePay and create it into binding library and use in xamiarn ,check docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/ . Second approach : use `MobilePay API `directly(web service) in your forms project , you can find the api on MobilePay official website .